# Find the formula of the sum of $\frac{1}{1+x^2} + \frac{1}{(1+x^2)^2} + \dots + \frac{1}{(1+x^2)^n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

How would I find the sum of this geometric series:

$$
\frac{1}{1+x^2} + \frac{1}{(1+x^2)^2} + \dots + \frac{1}{(1+x^2)^n}
$$

I want a formula, in the form of $\frac{n}{n+1}$, that can be proven by induction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like you would any other geometric series...
$$r+r^2+\cdots+r^n=\frac{r^{n+1}-r}{r-1}\qquad \text{ for }r\neq 1$$
Plug in $r=\left(\dfrac{1}{1+x^2}\right)$.

Comment: Got it: $\frac{(x^2+1)^n -1}{x^2(x^2+1)}$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: let $u=\frac{1}{1+x^2}\in(0,1]$. If $x=0$, then $u=1$ and your sum is just $n$. If $x\neq 0$, then $u\in(0,1)$ and your sum is
$$
\sum_{i=1}^nu^i=u\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}u^i=u\frac{1-u^n}{1-u}\to\frac{u}{1-u}\text{ as }n\to\infty.
$$

Comment: As n tends to infinity, "$\frac{u}{1-u}$.  How is this?

Comment: @satishramanathan Because $|u|<1$, so $u^n \to 0$.

Comment: @satishramanathan If $u\in(0,1)$, then $u^{n+1}\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: Sorry, I did not read your answer properly

Answer (score 0):

$$s_n=\frac{1}{1+x^2} + \frac{1}{(1+x^2)^2} + \dots + \frac{1}{(1+x^2)^n}$$ multiply $s_n$ by $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ then find $s_n-\frac{1}{1+x^2} s_n$ so 
$$s_n-\frac{1}{1+x^2} s_n=\\(\frac{1}{1+x^2} + \frac{1}{(1+x^2)^2} + \dots + \frac{1}{(1+x^2)^n})- (\frac{1}{(1+x^2)^2} + \frac{1}{(1+x^2)^3} + \dots + \frac{1}{(1+x^2)^{n+1}})=\\\frac{1}{(1+x^2)} -\frac{1}{(1+x^2)^{n+1}}$$ now 
$$s_n - \frac{1}{1+x^2} s_n =s_n(1-\frac{1}{1+x^2})=\frac{1}{(1+x^2)} -\frac{1}{(1+x^2)^{n+1}}\\ \rightarrow  s_n=\frac{\frac{1}{(1+x^2)} -\frac{1}{(1+x^2)^{n+1}}}{1-\frac{1}{1+x^2}}$$